# React-router not displaying jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

When I go to root link ("http://localhost:3000") jsx of the ProductListing component is not displayed but I can see console.log message that is written in ProductListing component.

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './containers/Header';
import ProductListing from './containers/ProductListing.js';
import ProductDetail from './containers/ProductDetail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ProductListing}/>
          <Route path="/product/:productId" component={ProductDetail}/>
          <Route>404 Not Found</Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const ProductListing = () => {
    const products = useSelector(state => state)
    console.log(products)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>ProductListing</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductListing
```

Comment: you are missing the usage of `BrowserRouter`, the provider needs to be fired inside App :)

Comment: @windmaomao . I imported BrowserRouteras as Router

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? I tried simplified version of your code and it works fine

Comment: @RyanLe Nope, no errors at all

Comment: Here is the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-sea-sfcse?file=/src/App.js) that it works.

Comment: import doesn't mean you have provide it, ` <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>`, take a look at online tutorial and don't miss each line.

Comment: @ktennie I posted an answer, please see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your error is laying on the import statement**

Change:

```
import ProductListing from './containers/ProductListing.js';
```

To:

```
import ProductListing from './containers/ProductListing';
```

Comment: simple pc restart did work! Anyway thanks for trying to help

Comment: That's ridiculous :D, Next time you can do reload window instead